# Is there any unique Id for android devices apart from Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID?

Tags: android

When device is factory reset, This ID is changing every time.
MAC address also not accessible always. I want a unique android id. which is always a unique value even though device is reset.

Comment: Google suggests to use AdvId, but it can be null or user can reset it to new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [Best practices for unique identifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) topic, but in short: there is no reliable variable/value in system across different manufacturers and versions, definitely not for reset case. If you want persist, unique identifier for your app then use `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` and store this value in e.g. `SharedPreferences`. It will persist as long as your app will be installed.

Comment: I am developing an app having device based license registration. so if the device is reset or app is reinstalled also license will validate throughout lifetime.

Comment: if user is again installed app on same device ,previous license details will fetch automatically from our servers.

Comment: well, there is no option for persist unique id on android, especially for reset case. you should build a system that connects licence with account, not device. then first log will bind account to generated instance `UUID`, any other log-in should check this `UUID` and for another app instance with same credentials and already stored, different `UUID` should ask user for allowing re-binding licence to new `UUID` (previous would be overwritten, any previous session should be broken)